# Update a table in a procedure where that table was not created

Tags: sql, procedure

Is this possible? I created a table in one procedure, I know it exists. Now I want to do an update on this table from another procedure. When I try to do this I get a "invalid object name" error. If I put the same update code into the procedure where the table was created it works just fine. How can I update this table from a different procedure?

Comment: Is it a temp table?  What's the name of the table?

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Are those tables on different databases?, servers?

Comment: If it *is* a Temp table - it is scoped within the SP. You can either use ##global Temp table (which is not recommended) OR create this temp table in a "parent" SP this way all SP that parent will call will have access to it

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to create tables in a stored proc except temp tables.

If the other proc does not recognize it I can see two possibilities. First you created a temp table and it is out of scope for the new proc.

Second you did not give the user who is executing the second proc the rights to the table.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a temp table or table variable, it will be disposed of once the originating sproc finishes executing.

Depending on the RDBMS platform (assuming MS here) you could create a global temp table (e.g. `##MyTable`), then pass its name as an input to the second sproc for further processing.

You might consider generating a unique datetime-specific table name if you want each run of the sproc to create its own table:

```
DECLARE @Now datetime, @TableName varchar(50)

SET @TableName = 'TheTable_' + CAST(YEAR(@Now) AS varchar(4)) + CAST(MONTH(@Now) AS varchar(2)) + CAST(DAY(@Now) AS varchar(2)) + CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, @Now) AS varchar(2)) + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, @Now) AS varchar(2)) + CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, @Now) AS varchar(2))
```

Instead if you want to persist the same table and reuse it, you could check to see whether it exists and act accordingly:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable_xxxx')
BEGIN

    ... do stuff to the existing table here, like truncate it or mark any
    ... existing records as processed somehow or whatever.

END
```